# while try to run a service within the container locally getting error?

Tags: docker, containers, windows-services

I'm able to run a windows service in locally by connecting the DB using Azure VPN.
but after building the docker image and running the windows container locally, when checking within the container that service is not getting up. and tried to start the service within the container terminal getting an error of

Start-Service : Failed to start service 'NotificationService (NotificationService)'.
At line:1 char:1

- Start-Service -Name NotificationService
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandExc  
  eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
  ```

anyone faced this issue before and please give me an solution?

I tried to run the windows service locally and it's up and running but when try to run the service within the container locally it's not getting up .

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], including for example your Dockerfile?  I'd normally expect a container to start its process on its own when you `docker run` it, you should rarely if ever need an interactive shell inside a container.